# Is there terminology around a bivariate function that is dependent on only one of its two arguments?

Tags: terminology, independence, bivariate-distributions

For example, if $f$ can be defined by $f(x, y) = g(x)$ for some $g$ and all $x$, are there any special adjectives that are applicable to $f$?

Comment: In the context of differential equations, such a function might be called autonomous. In general I've never heard of anything.

Comment: I might say “constant in $y$.”